# How to allow HTML tags into WP Bakery (formerly Visual Composer) `textfield` parameter

Tags: plugins, sanitization

While writing a custom element for WC Bakery (formerly Visual Composer) I've discovered that the HTML tags are being stripped from the `textfield` parameter type. It's sanitizing the `textfield` value by default.

I could not find a way to disable the `textfield` sanitization.

How can I allow HTML tags to be entered into this field?

Comment: the trick with this is to only do edittion on the "text" tab and never switch to "visual" tab

Comment: @TemaniAfif thats not related to this question, its not written very clearly but its about writing custom elements for Visual Composer (now WP Bakery), which just has a plain text area but if you try to add complex html into it then it gets stripped. Seems to work for simple stuff like `strong` though.

Comment: @rtpHarry I know this very well :) and it's related because the solution I use everyday is to consider the text tab where you can add code like want but if you switch to visual tab some of the code will disappear so I never switch to visual tab ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes you are correct that you shouldn't swap the text tab to visual or it will mess up your markup -- but thats not whats being asked about here. Op is asking about the Visual Composer `textfield` param type which I linked to in my answer below. It's front end is not the tinymce based editor, it is a simple, plain `textarea` tag and it will strip the html in some situations.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the type from `textarea` to `textarea_raw_html`:

- https://kb.wpbakery.com/docs/inner-api/vc_map/

Under the section "Available type values" it says:

> textarea_raw_html: Text area, its content will be coded into base64 (this allows you to store raw js or raw html code)

Although I'm not sure why they can base64 encode the output from this but not the `textarea_html` box with its nice formatting - an annoying limitation.

**UPDATE** It looks like you have to jump through some hoops when you switch to the `textarea_raw_html` param type.

To use the value you need to manually decode it with:

```
$atts['some_param'] =  rawurldecode( base64_decode( $atts['some_param'] ) );
```

Comment: How to set default value for this field?

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the vc_map param as param_name = 'content' the html wont get stripped off. The problem is you can only put one content.

```
array(
                'type' => 'textarea',
                'heading' => esc_html__( 'Texto', 'bauhaus' ),
                'param_name' => 'content',
                'holder' => 'div'
            ),
```

```
add_shortcode( 'custom_bloque_informativo', 'custom_bloque_informativo_func' );
function custom_bloque_informativo_func( $atts, $content ) {
    ob_start();
}
```